# I don't want any cache in my angular application with grunt and nodejs server

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs

I'm using grunt to serve my angular web application.
This application makes ajax calls to my nodejs server.

I can see that requests to my nodejs server are never made. This means that my application uses data from cache but I didn't enable any cache for any request.

What is making cache ?
- The browser ? I'm using safari and I clear the cache any time.
- Grunt ? I don't know if grunt caches the results
- My nodejs server ? I don't know if there is an option to indicate to not cache the response. I'm using express.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "I can see that requests to my nodejs server are never made."? If you monitor your node.js server's log do you see any incoming request?

Comment: I moinitor my node.js server and I can not see any incoming request, that's why I say "I can see that requests to my nodejs server are never made." When I restart grunt, only one request is made

Comment: Are you sure the server is logging every incoming request? if yes check your client side URLs or use another http client to test your server

Answer (score 0):

Angular caches html templates by default.
Details: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates